# For- loop, int ,python2-7

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, int

i have this code :

```
for item in data['main']:
    if item['temp']==293:
        print 3
```

and   the python shell tell me that i have

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: this is all the programm

import urllib2
import json

i have one url with api
json_obj=urllib2.urlopen(url)



data = json.load(json_obj)

Comment: sorry first  time i  do a comment ....

Comment: The problem is exactly what the error message tells you.

Comment: yea i dont know hot to fix it

Comment: Either `data` or `item` is a string. You can not use the string `temp` to index into the string, you can only index with integers.

Comment: use `print(item)`  and/or `print(data)` to see what you have.

Comment: i dont want to print all the dict i want to  do one if  that check  the temp is  == 293

Comment: for ex 
for item in data['weather']:
    if item['description']== "sky is clear":
        print 1   
 this dont have a problem !

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop is supposed to be like:

```
for i in range(27):
    print "PythonMaster is Jon Skeet's sock"
```

where the thing after `in` is `range`or a name of a list:

```
list = ["Python", "Master"]
for x in list:
    print x
```

Second, when accessing a list, you need to use integers:

```
list = ["", ""]
print list[0], list[1]  #Correct
print list["yolo"]      #Type error
```

So either fix the code after `in` or simply remove the `['main']` part so you have:

```
for item in data:
    if item == 293:
        print 3
```

Also, `item['temp']` will raise a TypeError as well. Read here for more info: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop